# How can i change files prefix in MySQL from .mp4 to .mp3

Tags: mysql

In a table in MySQL I have 10000 records and in one of the fields I have 10000 file names with `.mp4` prefix. How can I can *change/replace* all `.mp4` to `.mp3` using MySQL query?

Comment: pls show some table records.

Comment: tbtracks has 8 columns, one is trackname which contain filename of tracks e.g  has song1.mp4 ,now i want that with codes change all tracks name to same file name with prefix .mp3

Comment: It is not prefix - but suffix or file extension.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following mysql query to replace it with mp3

```
update tbtracks set trackname = Replace(trackname,'mp4','mp3');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find replace in mysql. To do this you can use the following query

```
UPDATE tbtracks SET trackname = REPLACE(trackname,'.mp4','.mp3');
```

This query will find and replace all occurrences of `.mp4` to `.mp3` in the trackname column.

For more details check out my blog post on [How to find and replace data in MySQL](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/how-to-find-and-replace-data-in-mysql/)